# Can I ask a question which is identical to what another question asked for prior to heavy edits?

Tags: discussion, questions

Earlier a user asked a question on Stack Overflow which attracted a good amount of attention and a lot of positive responses. However in the 2 hours since it was asked the user who asked the question has radically changed what the question is about, and the original requirement still exists but has been drastically watered down, so to speak.

I was intrigued by the original question to the extent that I'd like to know the answer myself. Can I ask a very similar question without all the convolution?

Possibly a terrible example, but if the question "What is `2 + 2`?" was asked, but later modified to be "What is `2 + 2`, `2 * 2`, `2 / 2` and `2 - 2`?", can I then ask "What is `2 + 2`?" myself?

Probably also worth adding that the question at hand hasn't received a clear-cut answer which solves the original problem.

Comment: The example is indeed rather terrible as it feels like any answer to the modified question would have to include an answer to the original question. But if that's not the case with the specific question you have in mind, and answers would be sufficiently different, you should of course be able to ask the original question again. It would probably be a good idea to include a link to the other question and explain how it's related but not a duplicate.